# Designing for Android - Resolution?

Tags: android, resolution, nexus-s, ppi

I'm designing an app for android, and the main devices we're targeting are Nexus S and Galaxy Tab, so I wonder which resolution should I design for and what PPI to use? I'd be using photoshop.

Surprisingly, I couldn't find a single decent PSD template for android while there are tons available for iOS, or maybe I'm just not looking at the right place?

Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Nexus S and Galaxy Tab both have `HDPI` screens. The layout sizes are:

- Nexus S: Normal
- Galaxy Tab: Large

For HDPI graphics the nominal resolution is 240 DPI. The size of a graphic should be

`pixels = dips * (density / 160)`

which for HDPI devices becomes `pixels = dips * 1.5`, where dips is the size of the object in density independent pixels.

This means a 16x16 normal (MDPI) icon should be 24x24 pixels on an HDPI device to maintain the same size graphic.

The screen sizes are:

- Nexus S: 480x800
- Galaxy Tab: 1024x600

so just make your mockups this size.

Comment: Google Nexus One - 3.7" - 480×800 - 254ppi
Nexus S - 4.0" - 480x800 - 235ppi
Galaxy Tab - 7" - 600x1024 - 171ppi
right?

Comment: Yep, but you can't design for each and every individual devices exact PPI, unless you really want to I guess. I have both, and a 32dip (48px on the devices) bitmap looks roughly the same on both, so designing for the guidelines works fine unless you want to get really fine precision on your layouts.

Comment: Hmm... so should I just design for 480x800 in hdpi(240) and 600x1024 in mdpi(160) - and the devices with similar screen resolutions will scaled automatically?

Comment: Yeah I think that's the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can see details for every mobile devices here (http://deviceatlas.com):

http://deviceatlas.com/devices/Samsung/Nexus+S/entry/2282190

deviceatlas.com/devices/Samsung/Galaxy+Tab/entry/1999308

deviceatlas.com/devices/Samsung/Galaxy+Tab+2/entry/2258482

deviceatlas.com/devices/Samsung/Galaxy+Tab+10.1/entry/2418093

You can use also Tera-WURFL script for detecting mobile device width by getting user agent from browser.
See demo here: http://www.tera-wurfl.com/explore/